# Unable to get promise value outside function ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get value of promise outside my function but it is returning **undefined**

Here is my code i have tried:

**Home.ts**

```
class Home{

dd:any;

constructor(public dbHelpr:DbHelperProvider){

}

getData(){

   this.dbHelpr.getRecordById("51").then(function(res:any){

               dd = res
                console.log("dd in "+dd);

              }); 

              console.log("dd out "+dd);
           }

}
```

**DbHelperProvider.ts**

```
getRecordById(_id){

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.db.get(_id).then(function (doc) {

        resolve(doc);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        resolve("fail");
      });
    })

  }
```

My Log shows:
**dd inside abcdef**

**dd outside undefined**

*How do i solve this?*

***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: did you  try this.dd = res instead of  dd = res? and logging like console.log(this.dd);

Comment: I have tried but got same error :(

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need dd value outside of async function? You want to use it in another function or?

Comment: sorry, console.log("dd out "+dd); works before because getRecordById is asyncronous

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I am calling getData() from other class so i want value of `dd` returned to that class

Answer (score 0):

Because `console.log("dd out "+dd);` is called before `console.log("dd in "+dd);` (because of async nature of promise) due to which you are getting undefined for `dd out`.

Assign `doc` to global var inside `.then` i.e.

```
  this.db.get(_id).then(function (doc) {

    resolve(doc);
    // assign to global var here.
  })
```

Comment: but i want global variable `dd` in Home.ts file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not using `arrow function`. Using a commom function in a callback will not grant access to variables outside of it, you need and `arrow function` in your callback. Also you need to use `this` to have access to the `dd` property of your class

```
getData(){
  this.dbHelpr.getRecordById("51").then((res:any) => {
    console.log("dd in " + this.dd); // prints undefined
    this.dd = res;
    console.log("dd out " + this.dd); // prints the value
  });
}
```

Also there's what VicJordan said about the async, since the second `console.log` is outside it's called before and since your `dd` property is not initialized with any value it'll be `undefined`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's nothing to work, if you want your `dd out` console to show the value simply move it insie the promise, will update my answer

Comment: in short I am calling getData() from other class so i want value of dd returned to that class, so i thought to store it in global var and returned to that class. if you can provide other way it will be helpful